# Flask Local and goble functions get and post

Tags: python, post, flask, get, local

I dont know how to call the function Regularhours with in  a get and post. I have a long list of functions i have load from a file and use in othre places. How do i make the RegularHours function work

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, render_template
from app import app
#this will go in anohter file 
def RegularHours():
    if Hours <= 8:
        return Hours
    elif Hours > 8:
        return Hours + 1 
    else: return 0
# above whould go to another file

@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'GET':

        return render_template('Option1.html' );

    elif request.method == 'POST':


        Hours = request.form['GuranteedHours'];
        print RegularHours()

        return render_template('test2.html' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example calling the function below, from the POST case:

```
def regular_hours(hours):
    if hours <= 8:
        return hours
    elif Hours > 8:
        return hours + 1 

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('Option1.html' );

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        hours = request.form['GuranteedHours'];
        hours = int(hours) # convert to integer
        reg_hours = regular_hours(hours)

        return render_template('test2.html', {'reg_hours': reg_hours})
```

Notice how I call the function, passed with the integer `hours`, and then captured the result into `reg_hours`, that is later passed as a context to the template `test2.html`

In the template, simply display with e.g.

```
<p>Regular Hours is: {{ reg_hours }}</p>
```